# Scroll Lock for single element using jQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, css, locking, scroll

The site I'm designing has a sticky header, and I want the header to stop being sticky, and start being static when it gets to a certain point. (something like the navigation on this site: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/css-powered-ribbons-the-clean-way/)

I'm only slightly experienced in jQuery, and tried to use the plugin their code links to, But it doesn't seem to be working like I thought it should.

Here's the demo site:
http://designdesignfirm.com/ahl/index.html

Even just the appropriate name for this kind of plugin would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this page: http://www.anthonymclin.com/code/7-miscellaneous/107-jquery-lockscroll-121

Answer (score 2):

There's a newer version of the script at http://anthonymclin.com/jquery-lockscroll-13